# Debug console doesn't show messages after upgrading Android Studio to Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1

Tags: android, patch, radiance-flamingo

I just upgraded the version of Android Studio to  Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1 and gradle to version 7.5 and I lost one of the most usefull features, the logs inside the Debug Console. When I run the app with Debug mode the only Log that's being displayed inside the Debug console is this:

Install successfully finished in 281 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "in.triosoft.astroworld/in.triosoft.astroworld.Activities.SplashScreen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Open logcat panel for Xiaomi M2007J17I (77bf66c5)
Connected to process 21628 on device 'xiaomi-m2007j17i-77bf66c5'.